# Safari and IE :hover with fadeIn effect bug

Tags: jquery, css, animation, hover, transition

I'm designing a simple web page and I am using http://jquery-jkit.com/ for my initial fadeIn transitions. I also have a couple of `<div>` elements, which have a `:hover` effect that makes them popup and have a small shadow beneath them.

On Chrome everything seems to work well. Whenever the `div` is in the visible portion of the screen, the class `go` is added to the element so that the `fadeIn` animation is triggered. After that whenever I hover on thee element, it pops up as it should.

On other browsers like IE (tested on 11) and Safari (tested on Version 9.0.3 11601.4.4), the initial fadeIn animation is triggered properly, but whenever I hover above the `<div>` the `fadeIn` is triggered again and the `:hover` effect is missing. When I inspect the element and manually remove the `fadeIn go` classes from `<div>` the `:hover` effect works fine.

I have tried removing the `fadeIn go` classes from the `<div>` with JavaScript after the animation is done but the moment the class is removed, the animation is triggered one last time. (`:hover` effect works fine after that).

Anyone has an idea about this?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4s39xdyj/3/)

Comment: can you recreate a small example in jsfiddle or codepen or something similar?

Comment: Hey @dewd, thank you for your reply! Here is a https://jsfiddle.net/4s39xdyj/3/ of what I mean.